# Is a correct YAML file enough for a correct ansible playbook, syntax while executing a role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

```
ERROR!
"unexpected parameter type in action: class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'"

The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/march/roles/apache/tasks/apt.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
---
- hosts: all
  ^ here
```

The playbook(apt.yml) which contains:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: uninstall git
    apt:
      name: git
      state: absent
  - name: update
    apt:
      update-cache: yes
```

Comment: *`"executing a role?"`* Which role are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"The error appears to be in /home/ansible/march/roles/apache/tasks/apt.yml': line 2, ..."*

A: The directives *`hosts`* and *`tasks`* are valid keywords in a [playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#intro-to-playbooks) but not in a [role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#roles).

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
```

---

> Q: *"Is a correct YAML file enough for a correct Ansible playbook ...?"*

A: It is not, obviously. The playbook presented in the question is syntactically correct. `ansible-lint apt.yml`, `yamllint apt.yml`, and `ansible-playbook apt.yml --syntax-check` report no errors.

The playbook was tested with the inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
linux:
  hosts:
    test_01:
      ansible_host: 10.1.0.11
```

The playbook works as expected

```
shell> ansible-playbook apt.yml -C

PLAY [all] ***

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***
ok: [test_01]

TASK [uninstall git] ***
changed: [test_01]

TASK [update] ***
changed: [test_01]

PLAY RECAP ***
test_01: ok=3 changed=2 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```